# Display SP list items in a custom view

Tags: list-view, custom

I am using SP 2013 online and would like to populate a custom table on the homepage with the data from a custom SP list. The list is populated through a an InfoPath form.

Example:

List location: mysite/site/projectsite/lists/projectstatus/allitems

Data I want to display and the format:

**Project Name:** ColumnName=”Project Name”

​​**Client:** ColumnName=”Client”

**Project Status / % Complete:** ColumnName=”Status”

​**Project Manager:** ​ColumnName="Project Manager"  -  **Service Delivery Lead​:** ​ColumnName="Service Delivery lead"

​**Project Sponsor:** ​ColumnName="Project Sponsor"  -  **Project Sponsor Email:** ​ColumnName="Project Sponsor Email"

​**Project Start Date:** ​ColumnName="Project Start Date"   -   **Project End Date:** ​ColumnName="Project End Date"

​​**Current Phase:** ​ColumnName="Current Phase"

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to create a view with all the columns you are listing above and show the list view web part on the homepage. You can use JSLink to customize the UI (if you are looking for a fancy looking table)

Here is a link on how to use JSLink to customize the OOTB list view
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a